# Fitting with Transcendental equation

Tags: python, curve-fitting, lmfit

I have a normal set of data, density of current as a function of voltage J(V). My goal is to fit these data with a model. The problem is that my model is composed of transcendental equations, so that I can not write a function in terms of J and use `lmfit`, for instance. My model looks like this:

Please have a look at the image

[image]

Any ideas of how I could do it?

If I solve the sistem with `fsolve` or similar, I would have to provide the parameters, so I don't know what to do.

I also tried to solve the sistem with `Scypy`, but it did not work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you will find a clean, easy way to do this -- please let us know if you do.

Since your functions are basically exponentials, you may find that taking a few iterations within the model function produces a stable, self-consistent result. That is, if values are "well behaved" so that the Voltage-drop perturbations (Vdn - V) are fairly small, taking a few loops to get to near-self-consistency might be sufficient.

Then again, since they are exponentials, for large positive values of V they are likely to diverge quickly.

Comment: Hm, not sure why my suggestion of an iterative approach to try to get to  a self-consistent set of values for the different terms Ji and Vi was down-voted.  I would expect it to work, at least for some values of the parameters. Is it proven to not work in this case? Have you found a better approach?

Comment: I did not vote bad. I still did not try what you suggested. But I found a similar problem in a book _Numerical Methods for Nonlinear Engineering Model - John R. Hauser_. The problem is that the book uses the _lua_ programming language. So I'm still dealing with that routine. If I succeed in doing that I'll post it here.

Comment: it seems you also did not accept the answer or up-vote it.

Comment: I'm sorry! I'm quite new here..I forget always to do so.
I still could not to solve it :/

Answer (score 0):

I think `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` has what you're looking for, I found [this tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scipy-curve-fitting/) helpful for my case.

You could perhaps do something like this:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def CurrentDensityFromVoltage(V, RS1, RS12, r, J01, J02):
     VD1 = <expression> 
     VD2 = <expression> 
     J1 = <expression>
     J2 = <expression>
     J3 = <expression>
     return J1+J2+J3

# coefficients to get CurrentDensity as a function of Voltage
param, _ = curve_fit(CurrentDensityFromVoltage, Voltage, CurrentDensity)

# current density 'cd' for any voltage 'v'
cd = CurrentDensityFromVoltage(v, param[0], param[1], param[2], param[3], param[4])
```

Comment: the question was asking about a transcendental function, in which the expressions for `J1` and`J2` each depend on `J1` and `J2`, and will change during the fitting process.  Neither `curve_fit` nor `lmfit` (nor any other numerical minimization method) will handle that explicitly, and one would have to rely on iterating toward an acceptably self-consistent result.   One may need to make a few such iterations at each evaluation of the model function, and possibly check for convergence of these iterations.